# Navigate child route Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have app-routing (for root)

```
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'swagger', component: SwaggerComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
```

I created other router-outlet (for child)

```
  { path: '', 
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'manufacturers',
        component: ShowManufacturerComponent,       
        children: [
          {
            path: 'add',
            component: AddComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'edit/:id',
            component: EditComponent,
          },
        ]
      },
      { path: 'products', component: ShowProductComponent },
      { path: 'categories', component: ShowCategoryComponent },
    ] 
  }
```

and LayoutComponent

```
<header></header>
<sidebar></sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Now this is router tree

```
AppComp
  --PageNotFoundComp
  --SwaggerComp
  --LoginComp
  --LayoutComp
      --ShowManufacturerComp
          --AddComp
          --EditComp
      --ShowCategoriesComp
....
```

When I use

```
<a routerLink="add">Add</a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink="/manufacturers/add">Add</a>
```

Only ShowManufacturersComp display. How to fix this problem, tks

Comment: Do you have a router-outlet on your ShowManufacturerComponent template?

Comment: @Ben Brookes no. I think everything will display in second router-outlet in LayoutComp, right?

Comment: If your ShowManufacturerComponent has `children` in it's configuration, it will need to have a router-outlet in it's template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowManufacturerComponent` is configured to have child routes.

In the component template you need to include a `router-outlet`.

Comment: But If Category or Product have Add, EditComp as child routes, I must add another router-outlet for each??

Comment: Yes, that is entirely by design

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried notation like this [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" ?

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink